# Must people shower after swimming in a lake?

Tags: swimming, hygiene

When going swimming in a lake, is there any danger in not showering after?

Generally I would shower if there were a lot of other people swimming and the lake was small. And if there was run-off from farms I would not go swimming in that water at all.

**Edit**: This question is about water that is safe for swimming, does not have cyanobacteria or any other obvious problems with it.
It does of course have some poo from water fowl in it and so on.

The lake in question is in the Netherlands and is the result of peat-excavation a long time ago.

Answer (score 4):

That is really going to depend on the lake in question. Generally, the smaller and more urban the lake, the more polluted it might be. There's a wide variety of lakes where I live (in BC, Canada). Most are fine for swimming. Some have official advisories to shower after swimming, to prevent "swimmer's itch". Some are mostly closed for swimming. Sometimes the advice is seasonal. You should ask around for advice regarding your lakes.

Comment: and the higher duck and goose density...

Comment: Actually there is 'official' advice, indicating which waters are considered safe for swimming and what the quality is. When cyanobacteria appear, this is indicated as well. SO my question is about water that is generally safe and clean apart for some duck poo.

Comment: IF duck poo is your only concern, and really the only contaminant, whether you shower or not depends only on your personal ick! factor. In the situation you describe,  I'd shower because my hair wouldn't feel right.

Comment: If I were to swim at Harrison Hot Springs, you bet my bottom dollar I would take a shower after swimming the lake. Swimmers itch is almost always present.

Comment: Interesting concept.  I've never swum in a lake that had adjacent shower facilities.